# Inflammatory and anti-inflammatory food table request

Tags: health, nutrition, food, resources

Is there a book, ebook or internet resource with a nutritional table (drawn from recent scientific studies) showing or describing inflammatory and anti-inflammatory characteristics of vegan and vegetarian foods?

Evidence publications

Total antioxidant capacity of plant foods, beverages and oils consumed in Italy assessed by three different in vitro assays. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12949370

Vegetables, fruit, antioxidants and cancer: a review of Italian studies.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11876489

Total antioxidant capacity of the diet is inversely and independently related to plasma concentration of high-sensitivity C-reactive protein in adult Italian subjects.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15975160

Free radical mechanisms in dementia of Alzheimer type and the potential for antioxidative treatment.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7763342

Screening of dietary carotenoids and carotenoid-rich fruit extracts for antioxidant activities applying 2,2′-azinobis(3-ethylenebenzothiazoline-6-sulfonic acid radical cation decolorization assay
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687999990377?via%3Dihub

A fluorescence-based method for measuring total plasma antioxidant capability.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7896168

Ferric reducing antioxidant power assay: direct measure of total antioxidant activity of biological fluids and modified version for simultaneous measurement of total antioxidant power and ascorbic acid concentration.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687999990055?via%3Dihub

Food selection based on total antioxidant capacity can modify antioxidant intake, systemic inflammation, and liver function without altering markers of oxidative stress.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18469252

The total antioxidant content of more than 3100 foods, beverages, spices, herbs and supplements used worldwide.
https://nutritionj.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1475-2891-9-3

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a cookbook out there that does this. There are many anti-inflammatory cookbooks. One of them probably has such a table. Gold is only as good as one's digging.

- Bey, Ronald - *Anti-inflammatory: Gout out - Vegan's Way- 50 Recipes- Halal: Vegan Asian Food*
- Bey, Ronald - *Cookbook: Vegan's Way - Kidney Health Recipes: Anti- Inflammatory - 50 Halal Recipes*
- Manski & Stein - *Vitality Diet - The Vegetarian Vegan Anti-Inflammatory Diet and Recipe Book*
- Moore, Melanie - *Vegan Anti - Inflammatory Diet Recipes: Healthy - Easy Prep - Anti - Inflammation Recipes*
- Press & Liaqat - *The Vegan Cookbook Anti-Inflammatory Vegan Recipes*

I'm not sure if claims made in these books are true. Although, there are descriptions of the anti-inflammatory properties of certain parts of the recipes in the previews to them. Enjoy.